# Controller unable to understand when UUID is sent

Tags: java, spring, rest, uuid, spring-web

I have an Spring-Web controller that is supposed to accept UUIDs as parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchBy", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String searchBy(@RequestParam UUID id) {

//...

}
```

I am sending to it a simple GET request with a UUID in the form of a String:

http://localhost:8080/myApp/searchBy?id=6ef4269d-d5ed-436b-9a26-9f0ffc39a795

But unfortunately it is sending me a 400 response saying Invalid UUID

What I am missing? 
The version of Spring Boot I use is: 2.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: Have you tried `@RequestParam("id")` and `@RequestMapping(params = "id")`?

Comment: Your code is working, at least on my system. Can you maybe provide more information about the code in //..? Have you tried getting the UUID as a String and then parsing it?

Comment: indeed the code works in my computer. could it be an error in the libraries? maybe you are using different spring versions...